# Equally distanced marker for non-equal distanced data

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, mark

I have a plot from my data using tikz, where the data is not equally distanced in y-direction. By using `mark repeat={10}` I can skip the plotted marker, but the markers are not equally distanced. As there are a lot of data points on top and less in the middle they cluster, which I do not want.

How to space them equally in y direction?

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.35\textwidth,
height=0.25\textheight,
at={(0in,01in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.1,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Mass fraction $OH$ [-]},
separate axis lines,
every y tick/.append style={mycolor1},
ymin=0,
ymax=6E-3,
ylabel={$\text{Distance [m]}$},
xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
xlabel style={font=\small},
yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
ylabel style={font=\small},
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot[color=mycolor1, forget plot,mark=o,mark repeat={10}] table [x=oh, y=y-coordinate, col sep=comma] {tikz_pictures/ISAT_Inde/JAXA-Sc07-Pr085-EDC-4-001.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: I think, the [`decorations.markings` library](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf/decoration/mark) could help here.